# Join multiple Geometry Node's mesh primitives to one to be able to bevel or subdivide them

Tags: geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface

For my project, it made necessary to build a cube from 6 separate faces, because a need to controll the material for every single face. I'm open for suggestions on different aproaches.

I was able to build it, but when i tested with a Subdivision surface on the joined mesh, the faces subdivided separately.

I guess i need to join the meshes, instead of the geometry, but I have no clue on how to do this.

[image]

Here is what i got untill now. All the faces(grids) with thir calculations joining into a single geometry.

Thank you, already.

Answer (score 2):

To assign separate materials to the faces of a cube, you don't need to start with separate planes. You can simply utilize the *Selection* socket of the *Set Material* node, and assign materials to them based on their *Index* number:

[image]

That setup assumes the cube is made out of single faces. If you need to, for example, subdivide them before assigning materials, or you really need to start with separate faces for some other reason, you can use the *Merge by Distance* node after *Join Geometry* to "join the meshes instead of the geometry", as you say:

[image]

Comment: The merge by distance is what I was looking for. But the what you suggested makes more sense. Thank you very much.